# Android Google Maps show location without internet

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using `SupportMapFragment` and when I use `GoogleMap` with Internet it is easy to show blue point from GoogleMaps Android to show my location and zoom camera to it, but when my app is in offline mode but location is on I can easily zoom to my location but can't show that blue point.

`if (mGoogleMap != null) {
            List<RestaurantDTO> local = new ArrayList<>();
            local.addAll(mRestData);
            mGoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new RestaurantAdapter());
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getMyLocation();
            mGoogleMap.getFocusedBuilding();`

So here I think main  `mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` and `mGoogleMap.getMyLocation();` methods so that when I delete then it doesn't show my blue circle pin.

Comment: may be using your network provider

Comment: @Androider , could you please explain a bit more.

Comment: @KirillZotov can you please edit your answer to show the code?

Comment: If you reinstall your application, the mapView wont have its cache, so it cant show the blue dot for your location. But if you have internet connection, and open your app, turn off internet, close your app, and reopen your app, it will show the blue dot, because it use the cache for the mapView.

Comment: Hmm, in my case it is not showing, is there any way to check if it is caching or obey map to hash itself?

Answer (score 1):

Map doesn't cache anything, you need to check if you have internet connection and set location source

```
 if (!CommonUtils.isHasInternetConnection(mCtx)) {    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.blue_google_maps_img)));
                LocationSource source = new LocationSource() {
                    @Override
                    public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener onLocationChangedListener) {
                        Location location = new Location("myProvider");
                        location.setLatitude(mCurrLatLng.latitude);
                        location.setLongitude(mCurrLatLng.longitude);
                        onLocationChangedListener.onLocationChanged(location);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void deactivate() {
                    }
                };
                mGoogleMap.setLocationSource(source);
            }
```